# python string to symbolic name

Tags: python

I want to check imported names.
Code:

```
import fst # empty file fst.py
for s in dir(fst):
    print(s) # got string with symbolic names
```

Output:

```
__builtins__
__cached__
__doc__
__file__
__name__
__package__
```

Now I want to check values of each defined name:
Code:

```
print(__builtins__)
print(__cached__)
print(__doc__)
print(__file__)
print(__name__)
print(__package__)
```

Question: How can I "extract" symbolic name from string?
supposed code:

```
import fst #empty file fst.py
for s in dir(fst):
    print(s, StrToSym(s)) # this call should be equal to str("__name__", __name__)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr):

```
for s in dir(fst):
  print (getattr(fst, s))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `getattr` function:

```
print(s, getattr(fst, s))
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing as a "symbolic name". What module contains is available as its attributes, so `getattr(module, name)` is what you're looking for.